# Split the toggle buttons into multiple rows

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, material-ui, togglebutton

Code:

```
<mat-button-toggle-group value="0" (change)="toggleChangeQuestion($event)" name="selectQuestions" #group2="matButtonToggleGroup">
    <div *ngFor="let item of test; let i = index;">
        <mat-button-toggle *ngIf="!item.answer" value="{{i}}">{{i}}</mat-button-toggle>
    </div>
</mat-button-toggle-group>
```

This is how it looks when test.length is greater than 5 :

[image: Result]

The desired output:

[image]

I have tried various combinations of display, width and height CSS but nothing works. How can I split the buttons into rows?

Comment: You only need 2 ngfor , other code is good,

1 ng for for row 
another ng for for 1.2.3.... (set maxlimit to 5 for 5 numbers)

Comment: Can you share an example for that? I can't find the proper nested ngFor example needed for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/278/how-to-split-an-array-into-chunks-of-the-same-size-easily-in-javascript) article, you can do a little function to split your first array into arrays of same length.

Once you got your array of array you can easily iterate over the arrays in your array as @Frost said in a comment.

```
<mat-button-toggle-group value="0" (change)="toggleChangeQuestion($event)" name="selectQuestions" #group2="matButtonToggleGroup">
  <div *ngFor="let array of test">
    <div *ngFor="let item of array; let i = index">
      <mat-button-toggle *ngIf="!item.answer" value="{{i}}">{{i}}</mat-button-toggle>
    </div>
  </div>
</mat-button-toggle-group>
```

If you want to keep your array of 1 dimension, you should iterate over it and use modulo to add a blank element to go to next line as follow

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of test; let i = index">
  <div style="display:block" *ngIf="i%5 == 0">
  </div>
  {{i}}
</ng-container>
```

Comment: I had to change `let item to array` to `let item of array` to compile. After that i am getting `Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.` this error.

Comment: Have you created a function as in the article I suggest you ? This function should create an array of array. And for the to, it was my bad, I have edited it.

Comment: I have edited with another solution where you don't need to split your array

Comment: I have already tried the second solution, it does not work as I thought it would. The `display: block` is not moving it to the next line. BUT the first solution worked perfectly *-* thou I had to play with the CSS of toggle-group and both the divs to make it look like the second image but now it's functional exactly as I wanted. Thank you very much for the help :)